# Why is my script to show markers on a google map not working?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

tried to make some markers on my google map but it wasnt a number so it didnt work, i tried to put parseFloat to convert it to a number but it still didnt work.

JavaScript code

```
var urlApi = "https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=lyon&apiKey=";

function initMap(){

//map options
    var options ={
        zoom:13,
        center:{lat:45.7563172, lng:4.827523}
    }
//new map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);

//new markers
$.getJSON(urlApi, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position : {
            lat : (parseFloat(item.lat)), 
            Ing : (parseFloat (item.Ing))
        },
      })
    })
  })
};
```

Comment: how about without () in lat and lng just parseFloat(item.lat)

Comment: Nope, didnt work. Thanks for the quick answer tho

Comment: What does the response from the service look like?  Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: You have two typos in the posted code `Ing : (parseFloat (item.Ing))` should be `lng : (parseFloat (item.lng))` (both of) the "I" (capital I) should be a lower case "L". ([proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k2dr8zpn/))

Comment: @geocodezip I feel so stupid ... It almost works now, it doesnt show a error anymore but now it shows me NaN, how can protest protect against NAN input ?

Comment: Can you update [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/k2dr8zpn/) to demonstrate your (new) issue?  Does the response not always include (valid) coordinates?

Comment: @geocodezip Sure, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/0dtg47pk/

Comment: i think this could be usefull. This how one out the 387 elements looks like. edit : Fixed it, thank you very much for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new marker but never using it :

```
new google.maps.Marker({ // This doesn't do anything by itself
```

As mentioned [in the doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add), you need to use `setMap` :

```
// To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
marker.setMap(map);
```

So your last code block should look like this :

```
//new markers
$.getJSON(urlApi, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(item) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: (parseFloat(item.lat)), 
            lng: (parseFloat(item.lng))
        },
      })
      marker.setMap(map);
    })
  })
};
```

Comment: It still says "setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lng: not a number in the console. " It it possible that this works for only one marker at the time. I have 396 to place.

Comment: If `item` has a `latLon` object property you don't need to build the object yourself, you can just pass it in as an argument for position. If you do need to build it yourself, you need to protect against `NAN` input.

Comment: You don't *need* to use `setMap`. You can use the [`map`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions.map) Marker option in such a case.